# Is there any way to convert Java object to JSON file

Tags: java, json, gson

Is there any way to convert Java object to JSON file ( I have array of objects and I want to export to JSON file, properties ) >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure there is, I suggest you to try [Google's API](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) which provides a good boxed way to serialize/deserialize data from java objects to JSON and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the related answers here.
Go through it.

- [A better Java JSON library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JsonParser](http://www.json.org/java/) to convert the Java object to JSON string and you just write that string to a file.